# Plot from a file containing all my x and an other containing the y

Tags: python, numpy, gnuplot

I've got two files each containing 604 columns of about 50 rows (pretty much all different). One file contains all the Xs for the Ys in the other file ! The first Y column goes with the first X column and have the same number of rows and so on! All the Xs are ranged from 0 to 1 but not with all the same interval.

I know that gnuplot does not have a native way to plot from different files. You must use the terminal and use the 'join' or 'paste' command. When using those, weird thing happens.

So the question is : Is there a way to have a plot with all those values ? A plot that would contains 604 lines of (x1,y1), (x2,y2) .... (x604,y604).

Also, I used python with numpy to create a list() of unequal numpy.arrays containing all those values. So if they're is a way or if python would make it easier, I am open to suggestions !

Thank you very much !

Edit : Here is an example of the files used:

```
x1.1, x2.1, x3.1 ... x604.1 

x1.2, x2.2, x3.2 ... x604.2 

x1.3, x2.3, x3.3 ... x604.3

...   ...   ...     ...   

x1.N, x2.N, x3.N ... x604.N
```

And:

```
y1.1, y2.1, y3.1 ... y604.1

y1.2, y2.2, y3.2 ... y604.2

y1.3, y2.3, y3.3 ... y604.3

...   ...   ...      ...

y1.N, y2.N, y3.N ... y604.N
```

I use no header nor columns title ! They are just plain csv files where the comma separates columns.

Comment: Take a look at Pandas :
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
You should try to open your csv (I assume you have csv files) to put them into 2 different 2D arrays. Then, you use something like matplotlib to plot your arrays : http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html
Good luck

Comment: @Hugo ! Thank you, in my search I've encountered pandas and tried it! I don't know why, but it would not let me name each columns (pd.read_csv(file,colnames=range(604)) or something like it. I wanted to name them in order to sort them so the X1 and Y1 would be beside each other.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put a sample of your two files ? So we can see the header and a few lines. If there is a header line in your files, you can use the `header` option of pd.read_csv() . If your two files' columns are in the same order it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Hugo, Thanks again! There you go !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can effectively do it with Pandas, which can manage missing values. but *the first line of your file must be the longest of all* .  Pandas determine the width of the dataframe with the header line.

As an example :

Suppose x.csv is :

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
1,2
```

add a first col, as long or more than the longest :

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
1,2
```

then read : `x=pd.read_csv('x.csv')` and `y=pd.read_csv('y.csv')`.

`plt.plot(x.T,y.T)` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First, I edited to show you what my files looks like ! Second, I'm guessing I should add the same line (length) to both the files ?

Comment: Holy cow ! Thank you ! It just worked ! Can you please explain or show me where I can find an explication of how the plt.plot works and why I was not able to do the same thing in gnuplot and even OriginLab ? Also, I was able to do it without adding a column longer than my data, is it because I did not transpose ?

Comment: See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for how array are considered as arguments. matplotlib is the de facto python standard for basic (and less) plots.

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you for pointing that out to me !